# CSV import to t-test

Tags: python-3.x, csv, t-test

I have a .csv file with specific columns that I need to do a two-tailed t-test for. Here is an example of my .csv file:

```
Type|No.|Count
A   |2  |4
B   |5  |2
```

I need to assign the two types (A's and B's) to different variables for the t-test. More specifically, I need a for loop (I assume) that will use the No. values for all A types in the file and do a two-tailed t-test comparing the No. values for A types and B types. Then, I need another two-tailed t-test done for the Count values for all A types and B types. 
I have been looking at pandas, and that seems to be useful for sorting .csv files. I did a test with it that looks like this:

```
groupby_type = data.groupby('A_B')
for type, value in groupby_type['No.']:
    print((type, value.mean()))
```

This produces the correct result. However, when I attempt to do a two-tailed t-test using the example from scipy-lectures, I get an NAN result. Here is the code:

```
A_type = (data[data['A_B'] == 'A']['No.'])
B_type = (data[data['A_B'] == 'B']['No.'])
sig = scipy.stats.ttest_ind([A_type], [B_type])
```

When this runs I get the following message:

```
Ttest_indResult(statistic=nan, pvalue=nan)
```

I have no idea why this is getting a nan value, and am having trouble understanding how to get around this issue. Thank you!

Comment: try the [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module with '|' as separator when you are trying to read your file